# Python error '>function at' After defining a variable and assigining an if function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-3.5

I am creating a program, that will ask for a custom passcode. The aspect of code I am experiencing an error within has the following premise: After typing redo, it will re-ask for the input.

```
def redo():
    pass_W = 'redo'
if pass_W == 'redo':
      input('Please choose your password')
```

The code before runs well and ends like it should. However, after typing redo the following appears:

```
<function redo at 0x000001B9371CF8C8>
```

Putting a pair of parentheses at the end of 'redo,' will make the code respond with nothing.

What mistakes am I making? What can I do to fix those mistakes?

Thanks.

Comment: you are not returning anything from your function. Mabye you want `return input('please ...')`.

Comment: fix your indentation - the code sample you provided can't work with that indentation. Also you always call functions with parentheses, I'm unsure what else you expected to happen when executing `redo` without them

Comment: `pass_W == 'redo'` is not an assignment...

Comment: What would one use instead?

Comment: @matt-333 `=` is assignment, `==` checks for equality.

Comment: You should look up the standard library's module `getpass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation was wrong, and the code was using '==' for assignment when it should have been '='.

```
def redo():
    pass_W = 'redo'
    if pass_W == 'redo':
        input('Please choose your password.')
```